# How to combine two plots from two data frame in one plot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two separate datasets with the same variables and already created two separate plots. I want to combine them in one plot.

Here are the codes for each plot:

```
##For tb2 :
my_data2$Date<- as.Date(my_data2$Date) #factor to date
tb2 <- my_data2
str(tb2)
tb2 <- tb2 %>% mutate (Month = month(Date, label = TRUE), Year = 
as.integer(year(Date)))

## plotting bar chart  
tb2_plot <- tb2 %>% ggplot(aes(factor(Month), GWQ)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity")+ facet_wrap(vars(Year), nrow = 1)+ 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size = 9))
```

---

```
##For tb:
my_data$Date<- as.Date(my_data$Date) #factor to date
tb <- my_data
str(tb)
tb <- tb %>% mutate (Month = month(Date, label = TRUE), Year = 
as.integer(year(Date)))
## plotting bar chart   
tb_plot <- tb %>% ggplot(aes(factor(Month), GWQ))+ geom_bar(stat = 
 "identity")+ facet_wrap(vars(Year), nrow = 1)+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size = 9))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the data prior to plotting.

Try:

`tb_all = bind_rows(tb %>% mutate(category = "A"), tb2 %>% mutate(category = "B"))`

If you want to distinguish between the two groups of data in the plot, you can for instance add `fill = category` to your `aes()` call.

Comment: Thank you @user2363777. I tried this : `tb_all <- bind_rows(tb %>% mutate (Month = month(Date, label = TRUE), Year = as.integer(year(Date))),
          tb2 %>% mutate (Month = month(Date, label = TRUE), Year = as.integer(year(Date))))` and for plotting `tb_all %>% ggplot(aes(factor(Month), GWQ))+ geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill='group'))+ facet_wrap(vars(Year), nrow = 1)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size = 9))` . It didn't give me any error but in graphs just shows one bar chart.

Comment: Apologies, in my reply I wrote `fill = group` instead of `fill = category`. Try `ggplot(aes(factor(Month), GWQ, fill = category))`. I would also recommend exploring this tutorial: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2)/

Comment: Thank you @user2363777.